# Any side effects of using the working instance object in synchronized block

Tags: java

I am making a class and there I need to synchronize between two methods "insert" and "getItems" for my use case. Although It seems to me that using the two methods as per as code below will not create any side impact:-

```
public class EmailBuffer {

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void insertItem(String item) {
        synchronized (items) {
            items.add(item);
        }
    }

    public String[] getItems() {
        synchronized (items) {
            String[] objects = new String[items.size()];
            items.toArray(objects);
            items.clear();
            return objects;
        }
    }
}
```

But can anyone helps me if there will be any side effects in using the above code?
Alternatively, I can make another instance variable 
private Object object = new Object(); and can use this in synchronized blocks in "insert" and "getItems" methods but this way, I will introduce an extra instance variable that is not needed at all if the above code doesn't have any problem at all.

Comment: Your synchronization idiom should work as expected, but the logic is a little fishy: I'd recommend documenting the fact that getting all "items" will actually clear the collection.

Comment: Yes, that's true..Documentation is pending. My requirement is to clear the entry once the objects are retrieved and therefore I have to clear the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any unexpected side-effects as long as you're not exposing your `items`. Your code should work as expected.

Comment: Although I was expecting the same but thanks a lot for confirming.

Comment: This is a nice article about syncronized blocks. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Comment: @Salivan I discourage you from `synchronize(this)` and using `synchronized` methods as they have an evil property: every component with access to your object can lock it and interfere with your synchronisation. It's much better practice to lock on a private member (instance or static depending on the application) as you can now make firm assumptions on how your synchronisation is working.